# UseQuery graphql -> useState with useEffect such that I can run second useEffect to set more state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, next.js, apollo

I am using Apollo for graphQL queries in a NextJS project I have the following request. I feel like the solution to this is simple, but the error occurs at the `stateData.allProducts` section it is saying it is null, but I have set the state in the useEffect and it has `data` as a dependency in the array, so shouldn't it re-render once data has loaded.

This is all works just fine if I placed these checks below a if statement checking the loading and return `...loading` but then I can't use useEffect.

Any help as to what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(QUERY);

  const Router = useRouter();

  // Creating state and setting it from query

  const [stateData, setStateData] = useState(null);
  const [disableAddToCart, setDisableAddToCart] = useState(false);


  useEffect(() => {
    setStateData(data);
  }, [data]);  
 
                       //~~~~~~~// <--- RIGHT HERE IS WHERE I GET THE NULL ERROR
  const productFound = stateData.allProduct.find(
    (product: any) => product.slug.current === Router.query.product
  );

  const currentItem = cartDetails[productFound.id];

  useEffect((): void => {
    console.log("currentItem", currentItem);
    if (currentItem) {
      if (currentItem.quantity > 0) {
        setDisableAddToCart(true);
      } else {
        setDisableAddToCart(false);
      }
    }
  }, [currentItem]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your query is loading, or if there is an error, the `data` variable from `useQuery` will be `null`.

Therefore you have to check for the `loading` to have finished and that no `error` has occurred. And/or for the `data` to be defined.

Also, `stateData` is unnecessary, because `data` is already a ready-to-use state variable.

```
const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(QUERY);
const Router = useRouter();
const [disableAddToCart, setDisableAddToCart] = useState(false);


let productFound;
let currentItem;

if(!loading && !error && data?.allProduct){
  productFound = data.allProduct.find(
    (product: any) => product.slug.current === Router.query.product
  );

  currentItem = cartDetails[productFound.id];

}




useEffect((): void => {
  //since you are using typescript, you can use the optional chaining operator
  if (currentItem?.quantity > 0) {
    setDisableAddToCart(true);
  } else {
    setDisableAddToCart(false);
  }
  
}, [currentItem]);
```

Comment: thx, this makes total sense, kind of forget to do these checks quite often.